# kohana 3.0.12 get a range of the multiple records

Tags: php, orm, kohana, kohana-3.0

I have a kohana 3.0.12 based website and I want to get the first 3 values from the database, then the following 3.
I know that in Kohana v2.3.x it could be done using `find_all(1,3)` method, so I have tried:

```
$restricted_footer_links = ORM::factory('static')->get_in_footer_restricted()->find_all(1,3);
```

but it retrieves all the values, like I would have done with `find_all()`. 
Any idea of how I can get a range of the multiple records in Kohana 3.0.12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix ORM with DB Query Builder:

```
$restricted_footer_links = ORM::factory('static')->get_in_footer_restricted()->limit(1)->offset(3)->find_all();
```

Comment: if i want to take the first three i put:                 $restricted_footer_links = ORM::factory('static')->get_in_footer_restricted()->limit(3)->offset(3)->find_all();

and if i want to take the next three ones?

Comment: strangely enough, it doesn;t work. i'll look more on it. thanks!